# "Unable to find project.json or *.csproj" while creating a new Interface or class in VS Code(1.32.3)

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am getting this issue **"Unable to find project.json or *.csproj"** while creating a new class or interface in my Angular project in vs code. It was working fine, but accidentally I am getting this issue. Due to this issue, I am unable to create new files in my project. I can't find any solution from previous questions.

Here is my .csproj file screenshot:

[image: Here is my cs.proj file]

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems an error of your installed "C# extensions" so, uninstall "C# extensions" And if you're using this C# extensions for creating interfaces or Classes then simply create a new file by giving its extension. Hope it works.

Comment: @BilalMahmood Hi, I am having the same issue recently...I uninstalled "C# extensions" and Re-installed but nothing worked out...Could you please explain detail what it means by " if you're using this C# extensions for creating interfaces or Classes then simply create a new file by giving its extension"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't right click the root folder and add interface, rather click the new file icon, add example.ts, move to desired location - and the error will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs for me in VS Code when I click on "New C# Interface" to be created in an Angular folder. This is user error on my part, what I should have done was click "Generate Interface" to create an Angular interface. No problem once I straightened myself out on this point.